# Remove gaps between polygons of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, arcmap, polygon, snapping, gap

I have extracted a polygon shapefile using raster to vector tool from TIFF image, and it has produced polygons from the Raster, but it has also generated the gaps between the polygons as attached in below image. What is best way to remove those gaps between polygons?

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this with two platforms and asked for a "best" solution, without describing how you got where you are. This may be an XY Problem, too. Please [Edit] the Question to provide more details and target the question to a single GIS platform.

Comment: I can't tell from your question but you might look at prepping your raster prior to using the  raster to vector or polygonize tools.  https://gisgeography.com/how-to-fill-nodata-raster-data/